# How do I convert an MQ4 code to Ninja Trader?

Tags: mql4, ninja

I need to convert Mq4 files to NinjaTrader and having a hard time using Visual Studio Code with Tabnine. I need help, please.

I need someone to guide me step by step to convert the code. I am suppose to have a convert tab with Tabnine but don't see it.